# Is multithreading what i'm looking for?

Tags: multithreading

I'm working on a program that would benefit from using multiple cpu cores. In the past while working on similar programs my cpu would max out at ~25% and I had quad core processor so will the threads distribute to the other available cores? Im a newbie when it comes to multithreading so excuse me I something stated above makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: In short, yes. With multiple threads you can benefit from several cores.

Comment: refer to this post [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18236597/when-why-should-i-use-multithread-in-java][1]

Comment: Multithreading was looking for you, while you were looking for it. You two crossed wires and missed each other. Concurrency does that!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you seem to have correct understanding of the problem.

When you write a single threaded program it cannot be shared/split among multiple cores. So writing a multi-threaded program may make use of multiple cores.

Comment: Does use multiple cores on it's own or is this something I need configure?

Comment: It should be taken care of automatically. I have done this in .Net and it doesn't need any special configuration for this.