# When to use multithreading in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am C++ programmer (intermediate) and learning multi-threading now. I found it quite confusing  when to use multi-threading in C++? How will i come to know that i need to use multi-threading in which part of section?

```
When to use multithreading in C++?
```

Comment: only when you absolutely have to :) although common cases are if say you are building a server which accepts requests on sockets. each socket would typically need its own thread (there are alternatives but they can be complicated). other cases are where you have a lot of heavy lifting to do. like encoding video. you can split the work across multiple CPU cores. things which happen based on a timer firing. also a good candidate for threads. but dont use them unless there is clear advantage. inter-thread communication can be complicated and create subtle bugs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When should you use multithreading? And would multi threading be beneficial if the different threads execute mutually independent tasks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7419619/when-should-you-use-multithreading-and-would-multi-threading-be-beneficial-if-t)

Comment: It's a duplicate, because using C++ is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @Martin - well, partially. different languages making threading more or less difficult. for C++ I would say AVOID, Java you might say maybe, and with Go the answer might be "you don't need to" :)

Comment: @SlipperySeal: The languages that make it so "you don't have to" actually handle it under the hood (At least the ones that I have experience with, which do not include Go, e.g. javascript). C++ just makes all that under-the-hood stuff explicit, and well it's not trivial.

Answer (score 3):

When you have resource intensive task like huge mathematical calculation , or I/O intensive task like reading or writing to file, use should your multithreading.

Purpose should be, you can be able to run multiple things (tasks) together, so that it will increase performance and responsiveness of your application. Also, learn about synchronization before implementing multithreading in your application.

Answer (score 3):

> When to use multithreading in C++?`

Well - the general rule of thumb is: **use it when it can speed up your application**. The answer isn't really language-dependant.

If you want to get an in-depth answer, then you have to consider a few things:

1. Is multithreading **possible** to implement inside your code? Do you have fragments which can be calulated at the same time and are intependent of other calculations?
2. Is multithreading **worth** implementing? Does your program run slow even when you did all you could to make it as fast as possible?
3. Will your code be run on machines that **support** multithreading (so have multiple processing units)? If you're designing code for some kind of machine with only one core, using multithreading is a waste of time.
4. Is there a **different** option? A better algorithm, cleaning the code, etc? If so - maybe it's better to use that instead of multithreading?
5. Do you have to handle things that are hard to **predict** in time, while the whole application has to constantly run? For example - receiving some information from a server in a game?

Answer (score 2):

This is a slightly subjective subject... But I tend to use multi-threading in one of two situations.

1 - In a performance critical situation where the utmost power is needed (and the algorithm of course supports parallelism), for me, matrix multiplications.

2 - Rarely where it may be easier to have a thread managing something fairly independent. The classic is networking, perhaps have a thread blocking waiting for connections and spawning threads to manage each thread as it comes in. This is useful as the threads can block and respond in a timely manner. Say you have a server, one request might need disk access which is slow, another thread can jump in an field a different request while the first is waiting for its data.

As has been said by others, only when you need to should you think about doing it, it gets complicated fast and can be difficult to debug.

Answer (score 1):

Multithreading is a specialized form of multitasking and a multitasking is the feature that allows your computer to run two or more programs concurrently.

I think this link can help you.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_multithreading.htm

Answer (score 1):

Mostly when you want things to be done at the same time. For instance, you may want a window to still respond to user input when a level is loading in a game or when you're downloading multiple files at once, etc. It's for things that really can't wait until other processing is done. Of course, both probably go slower as a result, but it really gives the illusion of multiple things happening at once.

Answer (score 1):

Use multithreading when you can speed up your algorithms by doing things in parallel.  Use it in opposition to multiprocessing when the threads need access to the parent process's resources.

Answer (score 0):

My two cents.

Use cases:

1. Integrate your application in a lib/app that already runs a loop. You would need a thread of your own to run your code concurrently if you cannot integrate into the other app.
2. Task splitting. It makes sense to organize disjoint tasks in threads sometimes, such as in separating sound from image processing, for example.
3. Performance. When you want to improve the throghput of some task.

Recommendations:

1. In the general case, don't do multithreading if a single threaded solution will suffice. It adds complexity.
2. When needed, start with higher-order primitives, such as [std::future](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future) and [std::async](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async).
3. When possible, avoid data sharing, which is the source of contention.
4. When going to lower level abstractions, such as mutexes and so on, encapsulate it in some pattern. You can take a look at [these slides](https://onedrive.live.com/view.aspx?resid=F1B8FF18A2AEC5C5!1176&cid=f1b8ff18a2aec5c5&app=WordPdf&wdo=2).
5. Decouple your functions from threading and compose the threading into the functions at a later point. Namely, don't embed thread creation into the logic of your code.